# Sorting a datatable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, listbox

I have an asp.net listbox on my page, that I want to sort.

E.g: listbox(lstChooseFields)

MY VB code:

```
        Private Sub LoadColumns()
        If drpScreen.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
        Dim daLookup As New LookupTableAdapters.LookupTableAdapter
        Dim dtLookup As New System.Data.DataTable

        dtLookup = daLookup.GetNestedControlValues("EM", "ExcelExport.aspx", "drpScreen", "drpScreen", drpScreen.SelectedValue)
        lstChooseFields.DataSource = dtLookup
        lstChooseFields.DataValueField = "LKP_ControlValue"
        lstChooseFields.DataTextField = "LKP_ControlText"
        lstChooseFields.DataBind()

        'Dispose

        daLookup.Dispose()

    End If
End Sub
```

I have done some searching and found something like 'dtLookup.DefaultView.Sort = "LKP_ControlText" that I can use but it does not work. I don't want to sort in my database only on this page, this listbox (lstChooseFields).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to sort for the datatable then you have tried 
 `dtLookup.DefaultView.Sort = "LKP_ControlText"` 
but you have missed out one piece of word there 
`dtLookup.DefaultView.Sort = "LKP_ControlText asc"`. This generally works if LKP_ControlText is a column name in the datatable

You must use the word `asc`there. which i couldnt find in your question.

After getting the dataTable sorted you can copy the same structure to another datatable if u want by using

```
Dim dtDuplicateLookup As New DataTable()
dtDuplicateLookup = dtLookup.DefaultView.ToTable(True)
```

and then access dtDuplicateLookup for further use if you want to retain the previous datatable as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **.sorted** property for the list box as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sorted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).

```
lstChooseFields.Sorted = True
```

**UPDATE:** your method was right but just tune it this way. I think you missed the **DESC** part. The second expression tells it how to sort the dataview.

```
Dim dataView As New DataView(table)
dataView.Sort = " column_name DESC" //DESC or ASC as per requirement
Dim dataTable AS DataTable = dataView.ToTable()
```

Else try this. **After sorting** a defaultview, generally  you have to loopback through it

```
foreach(DataRowView r in table.DefaultView)
{
    //... here you get the rows in sorted order
    //insert the listbox items one by one here using listbox.add or listbox.insert  commands
}
```

Comment: the i get the error Error: 148 'Sorted' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox'.

Comment: **dtLookup** is your datatable right? use **dtLookup.Sort = "column_name ASC"** .. Sort the datatable first and then bind to the listbox as shown here[1].

[1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ya3sah92(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I get the error: 'sort' is not a member of 'system.data.dataTable', sorry if im useless, but Im not that familiar with VB. AND if I try lstChooseFields.Sorted = true I get the error:'Sorted' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox'.